# Is there a way for others to configure constants used in my cocoapod or swift package library?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I created a library of basic SwiftUI components that includes a collection of colors, fonts, and standard icons. Right now, all the components reference a constants file for determining characteristics like primary/secondary colors, header/paragraph font sizes and typefaces, and other constants. I want other developers to be able to import this generic layer of resources and components and "fill in the blanks" in the constants file depending on their project needs. After importing the library, the developer can also add more specific UI components using the resources to tailor their own project's component library.

For maximum flexibility, the library is both a cocoapod and a swift package. Is there a way, after importing the package, to create some kind of object or configuration that is referenced by the imported module? Or am I thinking about this wrong/is there another way?

Generic Component Library --> More project specific component library --> used in team's project

*Example of constants file:*

```
public class MyConstants {
    
    // MARK: - Colors
    public struct Colors {
        
        public static let primary = Color(MSUColors.purple)
        public static let highlight = Color(MSUColors.purpleLighter)
        public static let secondary = Color(MSUColors.gold)
        
        public static let disabled = Color(MSUColors.grayLight)
        public static let text = Color(MSUColors.grayDarker)
        public static let border = Color(MSUColors.grayDark)
        public static let background = Color(MSUColors.grayUI)
        
        public static let valid = Color(MSUColors.checkmarkGreen)
        public static let error = Color(MSUColors.errorRed)
        public static let warning = Color(MSUColors.gold)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Icons
    public struct Icons {
        public static let reviewItems = TaskIcon.BillingSettings
        public static let dealerCode = TaskIcon.Customer
        public static let setAutoPay = TaskIcon.SetAutoPay
        public static let caretLeft = IconImage.caretLine.left?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        public static let deviceLabel = TaskIcon.DeviceLabel
        public static let printShippingLabel = TaskIcon.PrintShippingLabel
        public static let reviewAgreement = TaskIcon.ReviewAgreement
        public static let checkmark = IconImage.Checkmarks.self
        public static let managerLogin = IconImage.managerLogin
    }
    
    // ..etc for other stuff like fonts and sizes
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you question correctly, but what about creating a `struct ColorsConfiguration { let primary, etc. }`, with a `init(primary: Colors = .primary, highlight = .highlight, etc)` with default values and use this configuration (maybe a `static var colors: ColorsConfiguration`, that the user could change, and that you'll call if your pod/lib if needed to refer to user preferences?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm getting at. If the user could change/initialize these values, where/how exactly can they change it after they've imported the pod/lib into their own project? For example with cocoapods, after they write their podfile to include my library and do a pod install, where would they configure the constants for the library's components to use? My understanding is that they shouldn't edit the pod itself after importing.

Comment: They shouldn't edit your lib. Do you need yourself to access the user value in the lib code?

Comment: Not myself but other developers, is there some way to give the lib some kind of reference that can be configured by anyone using the lib? I'm starting to think this might actually be going against a best practice or is impossible